# how to fix oscillation in training and validation accuracy?

Tags: image-processing, keras, data-science, conv-neural-network

I'm using model made for Cifar 10 descriped here : 
https://keras.io/examples/cifar10_cnn/?fbclid=IwAR2gS_XgU59ISQh03khhVaSK3gbqB1aBFqRW7USOG7GjQIxNpFV74sGk8wA

My data has 26 classes with 75 image per class.

My problem is the oscillation in my training and validation accuracy and loss (shoed below ) how can i fix it ?

[image]